# How can I specify an interface that has child objects as the type for a function with destructured props

Tags: typescript

Instead of this,

```
import { client } from "./setupApi";

export const getLayout = ({ page, entity, list }: {page: string, entity: string, list: string}) => {
  return client.get("/secure/nav.json");
};
```

How can I use this interface?

```
export interface getLayoutProps {
  page: string;
  entity: string;
  layout: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine, the only reason your example doesn't work in my computer is because there's no `list` property in `getLayoutProps`, instead there's `layout`:

```
export interface getLayoutProps {
  page: string;
  entity: string;
  layout: string;
}

export const getLayout = ({ page, entity, layout }: getLayoutProps) => { // This works.
  return client.get("/secure/nav.json");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { client } from "./setupApi";

export interface IGetLayoutProps {
  page: string;
  entity: string;
  layout?: string;
  list?: Array<string>;
}

export const getLayout = ({ page, entity, list }: IGetLayoutProps) => {
  return client.get("/secure/nav.json");
};
```